# Places to look for office chairs made for shorter people

Tags: offices, ergonomics

I am 5'4" and find that all of the office chairs at my office are uncomfortable because of my height. My main issue is this: My back can't rest against the back of the chair with the inside of my knees resting on the edge of the seat. To temporarily solve this I place a folded blanket behind my back.

Has anyone else that has had this same issue had any success finding chairs designed for shorter people?

Comment: Have you checked if you can pull in the "back" of the chair? I have seen chairs like those in many offices. Also, are there any other short people in the office, and if yes, how do they deal with it? I don't mean to be condescending, just want to make sure you have tried the obvious solutions first.

Comment: @MaskedMan the chair I am currently using does not have the option to pull in the "back" of the chair. There are some other office chairs that we have that I will try out.

Comment: A quick google search tells me you should be searching for "petite office chairs" - https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ergonomic%20chairs%20for%20short%20person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try out other chairs in your office to see if there are any of a style that would work for you (those with the adjustable back support Masked Man mentioned or even any where the length of the seat is shorter).  If there are ask to swap with the owner or request that model from your office manager.  If not talk to your office manager about what other options are available.  It will somewhat depend on the culture in how accomodating they will be in finding special equiment for you.  If they are not useful there are lower back pillows that exist that are quite firm and made specifically for this purpose.

Comment: You might also go to your local office supply store and ask them to help find you a chair model that is comfortable and then specifically request that model from your facilites people.

Answer (score 3):

5'4" is well within the adjustment range of standard ergonomic office chairs; in most larger companies you can simply request a more adjustable chair.

In a smaller company you might look around the office for a suitable chair that isn't currently being used and swap it with yours, or ask a taller person if they are willing to swap chairs.

You don't mention where you are -- in the US your company is legally required to provide you with a chair that fits your body unless there is a special reason they cannot (i.e. you work on a factory assembly line and need to be tall enough to reach items at fixed distances.) What is legally required and what you can ask for without negative repercussions don't always match, though.